# ?? ReferenceError: goNext is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So, I have, in a code, a button, that when clicked calls a function called goBack, and another button that when clicked calls a function called goNext.

But the console always says:  ReferenceError: goNext is not defined.

Here is the code:

```
<!--JavaScript-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeState = 1;
function goBack() {
    if (iframeState >= 2 || iframeState <= 5) {
        iframeState = iframeState - 1;
    } else {
        iframeState = 1;
    }
    iframeSelector();
}
function goNext() {
    if (iframeState >= 1 || iframeState <= 4) {
        iframeState = iframeState + 1;
    } else {
        iframeState = 1;
    }
    iframeSelector();
}
function iframeSelector() {
    switch (iframeState) {
        case 1:
            iframeOne();
            break;
        case 2:
            iframeTwo();
            break;
        case 3:
            iframeThree();
            break;
        case 4:
            iframeFour();
            break;
        case 5:
            iframeFive();
            break;
        default:
            iframeState = 1;
            iframeOne();
    }
}
</script>


<!--HTML-->
<div id="buttons" align="center">
<button id="back" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>

<button id="next" type="button" onclick="goNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you testing this on site like jsFiddle? When I put it all into an HTML file, calling `goBack` and `goNext` works, and errors out when calling `iframeOne` or `iframeTwo` (expected as the function don't exist), depending on which button was clicked.

Comment: Your code works as is unless you are trying somwhere like jsfiddle as @mathachew mentioend

Comment: In my website, for some reason, the onclick="" event for buttons is not working, no idea why, but now I know the jquery equivalent, thanks to Sandeep, and it suits me perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the click event like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#back',function() {

  // goBack() method here...
  if (iframeState >= 2 || iframeState <= 5) {
    iframeState = iframeState - 1;
  } else {
    iframeState = 1;
  }
  iframeSelector();
});
```

Similar for other functions.

Comment: It works, I have no idea how, but I guess the problem was in the onclick="" on the button